# How do I throw exceptions inside async functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

my use case is something like this,

1. First I get the **image path** and **restaurant id** from the front-end.
2. Then I check whether this restaurant has 5 images already. If yes I send and exception says "Sorry maxmimum number of images you can upload is 5."
3. I want to attach that error to my respond as well.

This is my code.

```js
export async function upload_images_to_restaurant(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const data = req.swagger.params.body.value;
    console.log("Data", data);
    const restaurant_id = data.restaurant_id;

    const count = await db.restaurant_images.count({
      where: {
        restaurant_id: restaurant_id
      }
    })

    if (count >= 5) {
      throw "Sorry maxmimum number of images you can upload is 5."
    } else {
      const upload = db.restaurant_images.create(data)
    }

    console.log("Count", count)
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Errors", error);
    res.stauts(422).json(error)
  }
}
```

In the catch block console log it outputs the error.But after that it gives me an error

> This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch().

I'm wondering why I'm getting this error since what I throw is correctly output in the `catch block's` `console log`.

Comment: I assume the code in your `catch` block throws an error itself, which would be uncaught. This looks like a typo: `res.stauts(422)`

Comment: Felix Kling can you put an answer with this?

Comment: @FelixKling My bad. Yes It was a typo. =)

Comment: I'm assuming that `db.restaurant_images.create(data)` returns a `Promise`? If it does then it is likely rejecting and that is not being handled because you are missing the `await` keyword.

Comment: return a  `Promise.reject` in the catch block.

Comment: The error was catch block itself throw an error because of the typo in a catch block. `stauts` should be `status`. As well as what @JakeHolzinger is said need to consider possibly it also can gives the same error since I didn't use the await key word inside else block. But for this instance the error comes as a typo. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is a typo. You should write 'res.status(...' instead of 'res.stauts'. This exception is not handled by 'try... catch...' expression.